# Why doesn't "wish" have the letter "n" in it?

Tags: etymology, phonology

The English word "wish" is akin to the German word "wünschen", the reconstructed Proto-Germanic word being "wunskijanan" (according to Wiktionary). What happened to the letter n in the middle of the word? I see that the Old Norse word also didn't have it: "œskja", but for some reason the Faroese, Swedish and Danish ones do. Isn't Faroese a direct descendant of Old Norse?

Have there been analogous en losses in English? Does the process have a name? Or was it a random event?

Comment: Many German verbs end in *-en* where their English equivalent does not (there's *grüßen/greet* and *wollen/will* as well as *wünschen*) so it would appear unlikely to be random.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Oh, sorry. My question is unclear. I don't mean the _-en_ at the end of the word. I mean the letter n (en) in the middle of it.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I don't have a word for this specific case, but you can use the following general terms: *metaplasm* (a change (including omissions) in the letters of a word), *syncope* (shortening a word by omitting a middle segment), and *elision* (omission of a letter or syllable).

Comment: I'll add that I'm not sure if there's a cognate present that would result in analogous n-dropping, but n-loss before a fricative (in this case, I think it's a lingua-palatal fricative) is one of those natural phonological changes that takes place independently in many languages.

Comment: This is a good question, but can I urge you in thinking about this sort of question to consider _sounds_ and not _letters_. It is an entirely different kind of question from "Why has _debt_ got a 'b' in it?", which is a question about letters and not sounds.

Comment: @ColinFine I am well aware that my question is about sounds and not letters. This is why I tagged it with "Phonology". My first version had the intentionally vague "an en" instead of "the letter n". This turned out to be confusing so I went for the letter and it worked. Letters have this nice property that they change less easily than sounds so I will sometimes, when I don't care about rigor too much but do care about being understood, call an abstract phonological object a letter. It can be easier than deciding whether something is a phoneme, diaphoneme, allophone or whatever.

Comment: @ymar  We rarely get beyond the phoneme/phone contrast in this neck of the woods. I suggest putting phonemes (or anything of that general order) in slashes, thus:**/n/**, and phones in square brackets, thus:**[ɛ]**, and don't call them anything unless you have to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not my field, but I'm going to guess that this is an instance of the [**Ingvaeonic nasal spirant law**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingvaeonic_nasal_spirant_law), under which an /n/ before a fricative is dropped in Old English, Old Frisian and Old Saxon.

The article linked names several other English words which exhibit this change, including

- ***mouth***, compare Ger *Mund*
- ***us***, compare Ger *uns*
- ***tooth***, compare Ger *Zahn*
- ***other***, compare Ger *ander*
- ***goose***, compare Ger *Gans* (and note that *gander*, where no fricative is in play, retains the /n/)
- ***five***, compare Ger *fűnf*
- ***soft***, compare Ger *sanft*

The article also explains why some words, such as *month*, *tenth*, and *answer* appear to evade this law but in fact do not.

Comment: +1 Nooooo. You beat me by a minute. I'm no expert either, but this is the answer I was going to provide. This [table of vowel developments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English#Summary_of_vowel_developments) shows similar changes from the Proto-German to Old English: PG **tunskaz* > OE tūsc > "tusk"; PG **wunskijanaN* > OE wȳsċan > "wish"; PG **kunþiþō* > OE cȳþþ(u) > "kith"

Comment: @Zairja  I hope you at least have the consolation of working in other circles where you may earn Reputation by casually dropping the phrase *Ingvaeonic nasal spirant law*. You may still address the question of developments in Faroese and ON.